# Change dynamic height of a uitextview above uikeyboard using DAKeyboardControl

Tags: ios, uitextview

in my project I'm using this project:

`DAKeyboardControl` : https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl

To attach a `UIToolbar` with a `UITextView` above the keyboard and move it when dismiss the keyboard with panning gesture, now i can't understand how I can change the height of the `UITextView` and `UIToolbar` when I'm editing text, to add the `UITextView` I use the same code of the `DAKeyboardControl` example and I change `UITextField` with `UITextView`.

Now how I can change text view height dynamically?

Comment: To be clear, you want to change the textView height while entering text, or while panning? I have added an answer for the second case, but if it's the first let me know. I have handled that too in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this code in viewDidLoad:

```
self.toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                                                     self.view.bounds.size.height-40,
                                                                     self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                                                     40.0f)];
    self.toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    self.toolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview:self.toolBar];

    self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f,6.0f,self.toolBar.bounds.size.width - 20.0f - 68.0f,30.0f)];
    self.textView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    [self.textView setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
    [self.textView setFont:[UIFont tv_LektonRegular:16]];
    [self.textView setDelegate:self];

    [self.toolBar addSubview:self.textView];

    UIButton *sendButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    sendButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    [sendButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Send", @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sendButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sendButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont tv_LektonRegular:18]];
    [sendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendComment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    sendButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.toolBar.bounds.size.width - 68.0f,
                                  6.0f,
                                  58.0f,
                                  29.0f);
    [self.toolBar addSubview:sendButton];

    self.view.keyboardTriggerOffset = self.toolBar.bounds.size.height;

    __weak CommentActivityViewController* weakSelf = self;

    [self.view addKeyboardPanningWithActionHandler:^(CGRect keyboardFrameInView) {

        CGRect toolBarFrame = weakSelf.toolBar.frame;
        toolBarFrame.origin.y = keyboardFrameInView.origin.y - toolBarFrame.size.height;
        weakSelf.toolBar.frame = toolBarFrame;
    }];
```

then:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self _updateInputViewFrameWithKeyboardFrame];
}

- (void)_updateInputViewFrameWithKeyboardFrame
{
    // Calculate the height the input view ideally
    // has based on its textview's content
    UITextView *textView = self.textView;

    CGFloat newInputViewHeight;
    if ([NSURLSession class])
    {
        newInputViewHeight = textViewHeight(textView);
    } else {
        newInputViewHeight = self.textView.contentSize.height;
    }

    //10 is the border of the uitoolbar top and bottom
    newInputViewHeight += 10;
    newInputViewHeight = ceilf(newInputViewHeight);
    //newInputViewHeight = MIN(maxInputViewHeight, newInputViewHeight);

    // If the new input view height equals the current,
    // nothing has to be changed
    if (self.textView.bounds.size.height == newInputViewHeight) {
        return;
    }
    // If the new input view height is bigger than the view available, do nothing
    if ((self.view.bounds.size.height - self.view.keyboardFrameInView.size.height < newInputViewHeight)) {
        return;
    }

    CGRect inputViewFrame = self.textView.frame;
    inputViewFrame.size.height = newInputViewHeight;
    self.textView.frame = inputViewFrame;

    CGRect toolBarFrame = self.toolBar.frame;
    toolBarFrame.size.height = newInputViewHeight +10;
    toolBarFrame.origin.y = self.view.keyboardFrameInView.origin.y - toolBarFrame.size.height;
    self.toolBar.frame = toolBarFrame;

    self.view.keyboardTriggerOffset = self.toolBar.bounds.size.height;
}

static inline CGFloat textViewHeight(UITextView *textView) {
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = textView.textContainer;
    CGRect textRect =
    [textView.layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer];

    CGFloat textViewHeight = textRect.size.height +
    textView.textContainerInset.top + textView.textContainerInset.bottom;

    return textViewHeight;
}
```

this code works for iOS 7 and older...

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
CGRect textViewFrame = textView.frame;
textViewFrame.size.height = 200;// Or whatever you want, basically do your dynamic calculation before and assign the value here
textView.frame = textViewFrame;
```

And if you want it to be resized on an animated way, embed it in a view animation block like this:

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
         CGRect textViewFrame = textView.frame;
         textViewFrame.size.height = 200;// Or whatever you want, basically do your dynamic calculation before and assign the value here
         textView.frame = textViewFrame;
 }];
```

Comment: And where I have to put this code? I have tried in textdidchange delegate but the the text view go under the keyboard when increase...

Comment: You can use the code above when notifying about `textViewDidEndEditing:` delegate method, or you can register for a `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` notification and place the code in the callback method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `addKeyboardPanningWithActionHandler:actionHandler` method of `DAKeyboardControl`. In the handler block add your code to change the frames dynamically as the user pans the keyboard. You might want to set the `keyboardTriggerOffset` to allow panning when the touch reaches your `textView`'s frame.

The advantage here is that, even if the keyboard does not appear/disappear by panning, the frames are resized accordingly, as this block is called for all changes in the keyboard frame.

Sample code :

```
[self.view addKeyboardPanningWithActionHandler:^(CGRect keyboardFrameInView) {

    CGRect textViewFrame = myTextView.frame;
    textViewFrame.size.height = keyboardFrameInView.origin.y;
    myTextView.frame = textViewFrame;
}];
```

Just a sample, you might want to make some addition/subtractions in the line that assign the height, to correctly resize your `textView`.